# AWS Public Subnet - deny services deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

We are building some security boundaries for our internal teams and would like to limit their ability to deploy services in Public Subnets. I can build a boundary policy for EC2 not to be deployed in public subnets but this only covers EC2 service. Is there a way to block all services, existing or future, from being deployed in a specific subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS VPC documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-policy-examples.html#subnet-sg-example-iam) contains a solid example for permitting access to launch resources in to a specific subnet. You can conversely apply the same pattern with an explicit DENY to prevent an IAM User or Role from being able to launch resources in to specific subnets.

You policy will look something like:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource”: [
        “arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/subnet-11223344556677889"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```